# I don't understand how this algorithm will tell me if a graph is biconnected

Tags: algorithm, graph, connected-components

I'm doing some practice for an upcoming interview, and a practice question I found asks for an O(V+E) algorithm to tell if a graph is biconnected. [This](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/41graph/) page from Princeton says that a graph is biconnected if it has no articulation vertices, where an articulation vertex is a vertex whose removal will increase the number of connected components (since a biconnected graph should have one connected component).

One common solution to this problem is to do DFS with additional tracking to see if any of the vertices are articulation vertices. [This](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/articulation-points-or-cut-vertices-in-a-graph/) page says that a vertex is an articulation vertex if

- V is a root node with at least 2 children
  OR
- V has a child that cannot reach an ancestor of V

However, the condition for root nodes doesn't make sense to me. Here is an example of a biconnected graph: [image]

If we choose any of the nodes to be the root, they ALL have 2 or more children, so would be an articulation vertex thus making the graph not biconnected. This is a common algorithm for finding connected components, so assume I have misunderstood something. What do I actually need to check for the root node to see if a graph is biconnected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're supposed to do depth-first search, which means that the DFS tree always looks like

```
1   4
|   |
2---3
```

because you can't explore the `1--4` link until you're done exploring everything that can be reached from `2` without going through `1`, and you won't add `1--4` because it makes a cycle with the tree edges. No node in this tree has two children (`1` is the root).

Comment: I see, so a node is a child iff it is visited via the root node for the first time?

Comment: @CAJ Via its parent node, yes.